# Flutter: How to write data from List<String> into a File in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, file-handling

I'm trying to copy all Strings from a List into a File but only a few Strings are being copied.

I'm using [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) pkg from pub.dev to create a file on the User's device.

Explored questions related to File Handling but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Here is my CODE:

```
final Directory? externalStorageDirectoryPath =
    await getExternalStorageDirectory();
if (externalStorageDirectoryPath != null) {
  File file = File('${externalStorageDirectoryPath.path}/contacts.vcf');

  for (int i = 0; i < vCardsList.length; i++) {
    file.writeAsString(vCardsList[i], mode: FileMode.writeOnlyAppend);
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 'vCardList' is a List<String>

Comment: call `vCardsList.join()` and pass it to single `writeAsString()` method

Comment: Thanks @pskink. It was useful. Now may you please answer my this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77044580/dart-flutter-imports-all-contacts-into-vcf-file